# Exporting .csv from R & Batch file

Tags: r, csv, batch-file

I run a report in R every morning and I'm trying to automate this task.  I have a Windows machine and I've created a task within Task Scheduler.  I can get the file to run at a certain time, but I can't get it to export the csv.  My initial thoughts is that there is a disconnect between forward- & back-slashes, but I'm not sure where the break is.  Anyone have any thoughts?

**R_script.R**

```
setwd('C:/Users/Me/Desktop')
x <- runif(5)
y <- runif(5)
xy <- data.frame(X = x, Y = y)
write.csv(xy, 'C:/Users/Me/Desktop/xy.csv')
```

**Batch File**

```
Rscript CMD BATCH
C:\Users\Me\R_script.R
```

Comment: Just a thought, is your task set to run with the right username and permissions?

Comment: Please, don't modify the original question without advice; otherwise the answers that refer to a modified part of the original question seems nonsense... :-(

Comment: @Aacini - Sorry about that.  Still a noob!  Thanks for the heads up though and be sure not to do that again.

Comment: @Hong - Yep, I do have admin rights.  I'm the only one who uses the computer and 'Me' is the only username.  Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the first line of your batch file in a `cmd` window. It results in an error:

```
>Rscript CMD BATCH
Fatal error: cannot open file 'CMD': No such file or directory
```

And if you use `R CMD BATCH` it doesn't detect the input file because they should be on the same line:

```
>R CMD BATCH
no input file
```

Instead run the command in one of these two ways, with the file path on the same line:

```
>Rscript C:\Users\Me\R_script.R
>R CMD BATCH C:\Users\Me\R_script.R
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I edited the .bat file according to your suggestions and I get the same results.  If I doubleclick on the .bat file, it runs and creates the csv.  When I run this through Task Scheduler, it does not create the csv while the 'Last Run' column has been updated.  Any other thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks again!

Comment: @maloneypatr ummm, no, not off-hand. That does seem a bit odd. I'll have a think.